# TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was () -> handle anaconda spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

This is the code:

```
    import os
    import random
 
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Input
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model 
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, mean_absolute_error
 
    DATADIR = "./Dataset"
    TRAIN_TEST_CUTOFF = '2016-04-21'
    TRAIN_VALID_RATIO = 0.75
 
    # https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and- 
    recall-for-a-keras-model
    # to implement F1 score for validation in a batch
    def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
         possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
         recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall
 
    def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision
 
    def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
        precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
        recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
        return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
 
    def f1macro(y_true, y_pred):
        f_pos = f1_m(y_true, y_pred)
        # negative version of the data and prediction
        f_neg = f1_m(1-y_true, 1-K.clip(y_pred,0,1))
        return (f_pos + f_neg)/2
 
    def cnnpred_2d(seq_len=60, n_features=82, n_filters=(8,8,8), droprate=0.1):
        "2D-CNNpred model according to the paper"
        model = Sequential([
            Input(shape=(seq_len, n_features, 1)),
            Conv2D(n_filters[0], kernel_size=(1, n_features), activation="relu"),
            Conv2D(n_filters[1], kernel_size=(3,1), activation="relu"),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,1)),
            Conv2D(n_filters[2], kernel_size=(3,1), activation="relu"),
            MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,1)),
            Flatten(),
            Dropout(droprate),
            Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
        ])
        return model
 
     def datagen(data, seq_len, batch_size, targetcol, kind):
        "As a generator to produce samples for Keras model"
        batch = []
        while True:
             # Pick one dataframe from the pool
            key = random.choice(list(data.keys()))
            df = data[key]
            input_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != targetcol]
            index = df.index[df.index < TRAIN_TEST_CUTOFF]
            split = int(len(index) * TRAIN_VALID_RATIO)
            assert split > seq_len, "Training data too small for sequence length 
    {}".format(seq_len)
            if kind == 'train':
                index = index[:split]   # range for the training set
            elif kind == 'valid':
                index = index[split:]   # range for the validation set
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError
            # Pick one position, then clip a sequence length
            while True:
                t = random.choice(index)     # pick one time step
                n = (df.index == t).argmax() # find its position in the dataframe
                if n-seq_len+1 < 0:
                    continue # this sample is not enough for one sequence length
                frame = df.iloc[n-seq_len+1:n+1]
                batch.append([frame[input_cols].values, df.loc[t, targetcol]])
                break
            # if we get enough for a batch, dispatch
            if len(batch) == batch_size:
                X, y = zip(*batch)
                X, y = np.expand_dims(np.array(X), 3), np.array(y)
                yield X, y
                batch = []
 
     def testgen(data, seq_len, targetcol):
        "Return array of all test samples"
        batch = []
        for key, df in data.items():
            input_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != targetcol]
            # find the start of test sample
            t = df.index[df.index >= TRAIN_TEST_CUTOFF][0]
            n = (df.index == t).argmax()
            # extract sample using a sliding window
            for i in range(n+1, len(df)+1):
                frame = df.iloc[i-seq_len:i]
                batch.append([frame[input_cols].values, frame[targetcol][-1]])
        X, y = zip(*batch)
        return np.expand_dims(np.array(X),3), np.array(y)
 
    # Read data into pandas DataFrames
    data = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(DATADIR):
        if not filename.lower().endswith(".csv"):
            continue # read only the CSV files
        filepath = os.path.join(DATADIR, filename)
        X = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col="Date", parse_dates=True)
        # basic preprocessing: get the name, the classification
        # Save the target variable as a column in dataframe for easier dropna()
        name = X["Name"][0]
        del X["Name"]
        cols = X.columns
        X["Target"] = (X["Close"].pct_change().shift(-1) > 0).astype(int)
        X.dropna(inplace=True)
        # Fit the standard scaler using the training dataset
        index = X.index[X.index < TRAIN_TEST_CUTOFF]
        index = index[:int(len(index) * TRAIN_VALID_RATIO)]
        scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X.loc[index, cols])
        # Save scale transformed dataframe
        X[cols] = scaler.transform(X[cols])
        data[name] = X
 
    seq_len = 60
    batch_size = 128
    n_epochs = 20
    n_features = 82
  
    #  Produce CNNpred as a binary classification problem
    model = cnnpred_2d(seq_len, n_features)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mae", metrics=["acc", f1macro])
    model.summary()  # print model structure to console
 
    # Set up callbacks and fit the model
    # We use custom validation score f1macro() and hence monitor for "val_f1macro"
    checkpoint_path = "./cp2d-{epoch}-{val_f1macro:.2f}.h5"
    callbacks = [
       ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path,
                       monitor='val_f1macro', mode="max",
                        verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, 
    save_freq="epoch")
    ]
    model.fit(datagen(data, seq_len, batch_size, "Target", "train"),
              validation_data=datagen(data, seq_len, batch_size, "Target", "valid"),
              epochs=n_epochs, steps_per_epoch=400, validation_steps=10, verbose=1, 
    callbacks=callbacks)
 
    # Prepare test data
    test_data, test_target = testgen(data, seq_len, "Target")
 
    # Test the model
    test_out = model.predict(test_data)
    test_pred = (test_out > 0.5).astype(int)
    print("accuracy:", accuracy_score(test_pred, test_target))
    print("MAE:", mean_absolute_error(test_pred, test_target))
    print("F1:", f1_score(test_pred, test_target))
```

This is the error:

```
       File ~\OneDrive\Desktop\SAMIR\Nile University Undergraduate\Final Year Project\CNNpred- 
   Keras-main\2DCNNPredOG.py:6 in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:37 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
 
      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py:42 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import data

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\__init__.py:21 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.data import experimental

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\__init__.py:95 in 
    <module>
         from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\__init__.py:387 in <module>
         from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\data_service_ops.py:23 in <module>
         from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import compression_ops

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\compression_ops.py:16 in <module>
         from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:22 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.data.util import nest

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\nest.py:36 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor as _sparse_tensor

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\sparse_tensor.py:24 in 
    <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:25 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.eager import execute

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:23 in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

      File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:29 in <module>
        _np_bfloat16 = _pywrap_bfloat16.TF_bfloat16_type()

     TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
         () -> handle
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question**. Simply posting code and an error message is not enough. Your question should begin with a question word like "why" or "how", and end with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your numpy is the latest version.

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
```

If your numpy is not the latest version, try to upgrade to the latest version.

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```